# How do I know if I need world or object space when I am writing shader in cg?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cg

So I am writing a shader and I was setting up the light direction and normal direction to make a lambert shader.

```
VOUT.normalDirection = normalize( mul(float4(i.normal,0.0),_World2Object).xyz);

float3 lightDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
```

And the I wonderd, why do I need the normals in object space and the light in world space?

How do I know when I need to put somthing in world space or in object space?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your whole shader file? I also have no idea why you'd want the normal in object space.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sneaky one but it may well be correct, because the proper way to transform normals is to multiply them by the transpose of the inverse of the matrix that you would use for transforming points.